# SwiftUI iOS16 Table with expandable children (similar to DisclosureGroup)

Tags: swift, swiftui

I'm currently moving older SwiftUI code to iOS16. Previously i used a List with DisclosureGroups to create a table (code example below).

Ideally i want to use the iOS16 Table to auto create and size the columns instead of forcing a fixed sizes to have a proper column layout.

```
List {
    ForEach(someObject, id: \.id) { vm in
        DisclosureGroup {
            Disclosure(viewModel: mv.items)
        } label: {
            Row(viewModel: vm)
        }
    }
}
```

Does a Table provide such disclosure/accordion functionality?

**EDIT**
I forgot to mention that the children i want to display do not fit the parent table column. It would be a custom UI, to simplify lets say just a `Text` using the full width

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To my knowledge there is no implementation of DisclosreGroup together with `Table`, but you can mimic the functionality, here is a starting pint:

[image]

```
struct TableItem: Identifiable, Equatable {
    let id = UUID()
    let name: String
    let value1: Int
    let value2: Int
    let value3: Int
    var expanded: Bool = false
    let children: [TableItem]
}


struct ContentView: View {
    
    @State private var someObjects: [TableItem] = (1...30).map {
        TableItem(name: "Parent \($0)",
                  value1: 0, value2: 0, value3: 0,
                  children: (1...5).map {
            TableItem(name: "child \($0)",
                      value1: Int.random(in: 0..<100), value2: Int.random(in: 0..<100), value3: Int.random(in: 0..<100),
                      children: [])
            
        }
        )
    }
    
    var body: some View {
        
        Table(of: TableItem.self) {
            TableColumn("Name") { row in
                Text(row.name).fontWeight(row.children.isEmpty ? .regular : .bold)
                    .onTapGesture {
                        if let index = someObjects.firstIndex(of: row) {
                            withAnimation {
                                someObjects[index].expanded.toggle()
                            }
                        }
                    }
            }

            TableColumn("Value 1") { row in
                Text(row.value1.formatted())
            }

            TableColumn("Value 2") { row in
                Text(row.value3.formatted())
            }

            TableColumn("Value 3") { row in
                Text(row.value3.formatted())
            }

        } rows: {
            ForEach(someObjects, id: \.id) { row in
                TableRow(row)
                if row.expanded {
                    ForEach(row.children) { child in
                        TableRow(child)
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: DisclosureGroup with List works, there is no specific implementation, just the use of the together to achieve this behavior. That being said your solution is very nice! The only issue is that the children have to fit the table and can't just be text for example, can they?

Comment: Sorry, I wanted to write "there is no implementation of DislcosureGroup together with **Table**" ... I'll correct in my answer... for your other point I need some time to think.

Comment: Take your time. For now i stick with the older, kind of static way of doing it. The customer is happy with it :)

Comment: Always keep the customer happy :) I didn't find a way, it seems not possible to span another view over all Table columns (which makes sense if you think about sorting). Also tried with `Grid` but that introduces other issues ... so it might be best to stay with custom list.

Comment: I've also tried with Grid, no luck. I see why it doesnt work, but the scenario of children is very valid one imo. We'll see, maybe they'll present smth in the upcoming WWDC. - figuring out it doesn't work is also mission accomplished,  thanks for trying!